# std::sort on a vector of Objects containing Objects* pointers

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

Let's say I define the following struct:

```
struct dockPose {
    Complex* pose;
    int Cluster;
    struct dockPose* DP;
    float Distance;
    int Density;
};
typedef struct dockPose DockPose;
```

Then, I declare a vector which will be sorted by Density value using the std::sort() function. After the call to std::sort, will my DockPose* DP pointers still point to the same DockPose instance it was pointing before? If not, what can I do to be sure DP pointers points to the same DockPose it was pointing to before sorting (if there is anything I can do) ?

Comment: Do the pointers point to other objects within the vector you are sorting?

Comment: `typedef struct foo Foo` is for legacy C compatibility; there's no reason to use it in new C++ code.

Comment: Benjamin: Yes, they are.

Comment: Thanks Alan for the information. I'm used to code in C most of the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the pointers will still point to the same instance. But that may not be what you actually want. When you call `std::sort` on a vector, it does not change the location of instances (that's not even a thing you can do in C++). It swaps their values with each other. This is probably better explained with a simplified example. Take this struct:

```
struct Foo
{
    int x;
    Foo* buddy;
};

bool operator<(Foo const& lhs, Foo const& rhs)
{
    return lhs.x < rhs.x;
}
```

Now, lets say I make a vector of these, with decreasing x values, and each one having a pointer to the one that comes after it (and the last having a pointer to the first):

```
std::vector<Foo> vec(5);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    vec[i].x = 4 - i;
    vec[i].buddy = &vec[(i + 1) % 5];
}
```

Now, if I sort this vector, it is essentially going to reverse. But the instances themselves don't change their location. Instead, their values change such that the first one has the lowest `x` value, and it increases from there. Now, the pointer member changes along with the `x` value.

So take, for example, `vec[0]`, which had an `x` value of 4, and a pointer to `vec[1]` (which has an `x` value of 3). After the sort, those values will end up in the last element, `vec[4]`. So `vec[4]` will have an `x` value of 4, and a pointer to `vec[1]` (which, after the sort, has an `x` value of 1).

So, before the sort, the element with the `x` value 4, had a pointer to the element with an `x` value of 3. After the sort, the element with the `x` value of 4 has a pointer to the element with the `x` value of 1. I doubt this is what you wanted.

Since you are interested in the identity of the instances, not just their values, you should probably be using something like `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<dockPose>>`. For my `Foo` example, I could do something like this:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> vec;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    vec.emplace_back(new Foo);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    vec[i]->x = 4 - i;
    vec[i]->buddy = vec[(i + 1) % 5].get();
}
```

Note that when you do this, you need to use a different comparison function. One which compares the dereferenced pointers, rather than the pointers themselves.

Comment: I really like your suggestion and it explains what I saw earlier while testing. I will implement and test it later this evening. Thank you for the quality of your answer (I would upvote if I could).

Comment: Why not use a separate vector of pointers to dockPose structs? Then sort the vector of pointers according to the dockPose structs. The vector of pointers and dockPose structs would need to be members of the same class. Then you can use a function operator (functor) or lambda function for the compare function used by std::sort().  ... or did you want to implement some type of linked list?

Answer (score 0):

`std::sort` will just move the objects around in the vector, but the pointers themselves will still point to the same memory location they pointed initially.

Comment: except different things will be in those memory locations

Answer (score 0):

Sorting will not change the values of those pointers. Pointers are simply variables holding memory addresses, sorting a vector will not change any of the member variable data of the objects in the vector.

Comment: sorting will not change the value of the pointers, but you are moving the things that you are pointing at, so after the sort the pointers will  still be pointing to the same memory location, but there may be a different object at that location.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a vector of `DockPose` objects you are treating them as values, in which case it's a bad idea to keep pointers to them. I suspect you actually want them to be entities (two entities are distinct even if they have identical values).

In which case you should instead have a vector of pointers to the entities; sorting the vector of pointers will then not invalidate your `DP` pointers.

Answer (score 0):

keeping pointers to objects in a vector is not a good idea. Even a simple push_back() could make all of your pointers invalid, if you happen to cause a resize. 
If you want to keep pointers to objects in a container you would be better to use a std::list